# About to load a main class in a scala project with dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to use a main object in scala, but SBT returns this message:

```
> package
[info] Packaging /Users/aironman/scala_cassandra_project_without_play/target/scala-2.10/my-project_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /Users/aironman/scala_cassandra_project_without_play/common/target/scala-2.11/common_2.11-0.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /Users/aironman/scala_cassandra_project_without_play/main/target/scala-2.11/main_2.11-0.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 11-mar-2016 11:25:16
> run
[info] Running common.utils.cassandra.CassandraMain 
[error] (run-main-1) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: common.utils.cassandra.CassandraMain
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: common.utils.cassandra.CassandraMain
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last scala_cassandra_project_without_play/compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last scala_cassandra_project_without_play/compile:run for the full output.
[error] (scala_cassandra_project_without_play/compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 11-mar-2016 11:25:18
>
```

As you can see in my `build.sbt` file, I want to use a multi dependency setup with decencies each other.

```
name := "My Project"

val commonSettings = Seq(
organization := "net.example",
version := "0.1",
scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")
)

lazy val testDependencies = Seq (
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.0" % "test"
)

lazy val cassandraDependencies = Seq (
"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.2",
"com.chrisomeara" % "pillar_2.11" % "2.0.1"
)

lazy val common = project.in(file("common"))
.settings(commonSettings:_*)
.settings(libraryDependencies ++= (testDependencies ++    cassandraDependencies))

val projectMainClass = "common.utils.cassandra.CassandraMain"

lazy val main = project.in(file("main"))
.dependsOn(common) 
.settings(commonSettings:_*)
.settings(
 mainClass := Some(projectMainClass)
)   

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some(projectMainClass)
```

The folders of this project has the `build.sbt` file in root folder, and two another folders, `common` and `main`, with the same structure, I mean,

```
 aironman$:scala_cassandra_project_without_play ls common/src/main/scala/common/utils/cassandra/
CassandraConnectionUri.scala    Pillar.scala
Helper.scala

aironman$:scala_cassandra_project_without_play ls main/src/main/scala/common/utils/cassandra/
CassandraMain.scala
```

CassandraMain.scala code is too simple, just the package and the main function:

```
package common.utils.cassandra

import common.utils.cassandra._

object CassandraMain extends App{
    println("Trying to connect to Cassandra server...")
    //val uri = CassandraConnectionUri("cassandra://localhost:9042/test")
    //val session = Helper.createSessionAndInitKeyspace(uri)

    //session.execute(/* Some CQL string */)        
}
```

UPDATE 1 after @thirstycrow advise

I don't understand why sbt tries to look for common_2.10, because scalaVersion is set to 2.11.4 in commonSettings and as you can see, my scala setup is:

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:~ aironman$ sbt sbtVersion
[info] Set current project to aironman (in build file:/Users/aironman/)
[info] 0.13.11
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:~ aironman$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL
```

Ok, now i know that the lazy val of main MUST have .settings(commonSettings:_*), if not, it tries to use version 2.10

UPDATE 2, now i know that i have to change to project main and execute run command. Thank you @thirstycrow and @nabil.

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:scala_cassandra_project_without_play aironman$ sbt
[info] Set current project to My Project (in build file:/Users/aironman/scala_cassandra_project_without_play/)
> project main
[info] Set current project to main (in build file:/Users/aironman/scala_cassandra_project_without_play/)
> run
[info] Running common.utils.cassandra.CassandraMain 
**Trying to connect to Cassandra server...**
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 11-mar-2016 11:50:41
```

I have learned a lot, thanks again

Comment: Thank you Nabil for the response, i already renamed principal.scala to CassandraMain.scala and changed build.sbt file, the error is still there.

Comment: Thank you @thirstycrow, i already did what you told me, i had to modify   lazy val main = project.in(file("main"))
  .dependsOn(common) 
  .settings(commonSettings:_*)
  .settings(
    mainClass := Some(projectMainClass)
  ) in order to get compiled with correct version of scala. It was trying to use scala 2.10 version instead of commonSettings, returning an unresolved dependencies error, but the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: common.utils.cassandra.CassandraMain is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CassandraMain is in the main project, and you are trying to run it in the root project.

Set mainClass for the main project, and run it there with `main/run`.

```
lazy val main = project.in(file("main"))
  .dependsOn(common) // Should 'dependsOn' common if you wanna use common code in main
  .settings(
    mainClass := Some("common.utils.cassandra.CassandraMain")
  )
```

Comment: ok, now i have understand what you were trying to tell me. Change to main project doing project main and execute run.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `principal` is maybe the file name but not the class name.
Pleas post the content of `principal` for further information.
Scala classes and filenames should start with a upper latter.
Also check if your main class is an `object`.